# Trying to read image buffer from MongoDB and eject into EJS. How do I transform it back into an image?

Tags: node.js, image, mongodb, heroku, ejs

I am using EJS engine, with NodeJS, and I have an Image that I uploaded into database via fs.readFile. With the image object in Mongo, I also have a type attribute that says something like 'image/png' and a buffer attribute that says something like '

Currently, I am using Node.js and EJS engine on Heroku. I can successfully send a photo from MongoDB object to a webpage via code below:

```
res.contentType(contentType);
res.send(data);
```

However, this page redirects to the url I'm sending to. I would like to retrieve image and load it into image tag src but I don't know what to do with this automatic redirect.

How can I retrieve an image properly so that I can use it in my EJS?

P.S. I don't know if this is important but I will be deploying on Heroku.

Comment: Another person doing it the wrong way. Don't attempt to render an image within your template. Rather, provide an "endpoint" for your browser client to retrieve the image data just as if it were a regular file. Browsers have build in "cache" mechanisms ( where the headers are respected ) to not bother to pull in content when they already have a valid copy. So if you use a standard `<img src="something">` tag that resolves to your endpoint, then the server can work it out. Stuffing base64 encoded images into templates is a very bad design pattern. Use the browser performance optimizations.

Comment: Thank you, Blakes, for your comment. I was wondering if you could give me some implementation details as to how to get from NodeJS to my browser's local cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/image/:id',(req,res)=>{
        image.findById(req.params.id,(err,data)=>{
            if(!err){
                res.contentType(data.img.contentType);
                res.send(data.img.data);
            }
        });

    });
```

First write this to load the image , then make a request from a page using the id for the image .

```
<img src="/image/<%= id %>">
```